# What is an anamorphism, and how does one look like in C#?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, catamorphism, recursion-schemes, anamorphism

I am trying to wrap my head around the concept of anamorphism.

> In functional programming, an anamorphism is a generalization of the concept of unfolds on lists. Formally, anamorphisms are generic functions that can corecursively construct a result of a certain type and which is parameterized by functions that determine the next single step of the construction.

---

Its dual, catamorphism, is nicely described in this post: [What is a catamorphism and can it be implemented in C# 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196294/what-is-a-catamorphism-and-can-it-be-implemented-in-c-sharp-3-0).

A nice example of catamorphic behavior in C# is the LINQ's [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

---

What would an anamorphic equivalent be? Is it correct to think of a pseudo-random number generator [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) as an anamorphic construct or should the process of unfolding always include an accumulator function like the one below (code snippet taken from [Intro to Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableGenerate))?

```
IEnumerable<T> Unfold<T>(T seed, Func<T, T> accumulator)
{
    var nextValue = seed;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return nextValue;
        nextValue = accumulator(nextValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Wikipediaentry says Zip is an example. Which takes two sequences and "zips" them together. LINQ has a function called Zip. The example you provided suits the definition aswell. However there is no "finished" predicate, which is stated as optional.

Comment: According to http://enumeratethis.com/category/c/, `Observable.Generate` is an example of anamorphism. Though, like Aggregate, then aren't true implementations as they are not truly generic and are specific to certain data types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LINQ's Aggregate method has the signature

```
T Aggregate<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, T> accumulator)
```

So the corresponding unfolding would be

```
IEnumerable<T> Unfold<T>(T seed, Func<T, Nullable<T>> accumulator)
{
    Nullable<T> nextValue = new Nullable<T>(seed);
    while (nextValue.HasValue)
    {
        yield return nextValue.Value;
        nextValue = accumulator(nextValue);
    }
}
```

In pure functional programming, folding and unfolding must include a deterministic function. For C#'s `System.Random`, this is true if you consider its [deterministic internals](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Random@cs/1305376/Random@cs) as an implicit function, as you suggest. One could recreate this precise PRNG using `Unfold`, so it may not *use* folding but be *functionally and semantically equivalent* to a fold.

The two folding and unfolding of lists above are special cases of the more general folding of lists:

```
B Fold<A, B>(Func<A, B, B> acc, B seed, IEnumerable<A> source);
IEnumerable<B> Unfold<A, B>(Func<A, Nullable<Tuple<A, B>>> acc, A seed);
```

In LINQ, this generality is present in other combinators such as `Select`.

As [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196451/235908) to the question *What is a catamorphism and can it be implemented in C# 3.0?*:

> Catamorphisms in general refer to the pattern of folding for an
>   arbitrary data type.

Likewise, one may construct anamorphisms on binary trees in C#:

```
public class Tree<T> {
    public T Data { get; private set; }
    public Tree<T> Left { get; private set; }
    public Tree<T> Right { get; private set; }

    public Tree(T data, Tree<T> left, Tree<T> right)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.Left = left;
        this.Right = right;
    }
}

public struct Triple<T> {
    public T Result;
    public Nullable<T> LeftSeed;
    public Nullable<T> RightSeed;
}

public static Tree<T> Unfold<T>(Func<T, Triple<T>> water, T seed)
{
    Triple<T> tmp = water(seed);
    Tree<T> leftTree = null;
    Tree<T> rightTree = null;

    if (tmp.LeftSeed.HasValue)
        leftTree = Unfold<T>(water, tmp.LeftSeed.Value);

    if (tmp.RightSeed.HasValue)
        rightTree = Unfold<T>(water, tmp.RightSeed.Value);

    return new Tree(tmp.Result, leftTree, rightTree);
}
```

Here is a rather silly example of how to build the [Collatz numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) in [this XKCD strip](https://xkcd.com/710/):

```
public static Tree<int> CollatzTree(int max)
{
    return Unfold<int>(i => {
        if (i >= max) return new Triple(i, null, null);
        int? tpo = (i - 1) % 3 == 0 ? (i - 1) / 3 : null;
        return new Triple(i, tpo, 2*i);
    }, max);
}
```

Here is a heteronormative example of building a family tree:

```
public static Tree<Person> FamilyTree(Person youngestPerson) {
    return Unfold<Person>(child => {
        Person mother = GetMotherFromDatabase(child);
        Person father = GetFatherFromDatabase(child);
        return new Triple(p, mother, father);
    }, youngestPerson);
}
```

I didn't run any of the code above so there may be errors.

Comment: I need to use Trees more often.