# .Net Collections: Node-Leaf

Tags: .net, generics, collections

Is there a built in node-like collection that will allow me to store information within information without building long hard to read generic declarations?

C# or VB.Net solutions would be appreciated.

For example:

```
dim base as new Dictionary(of String, Dictionary(of String, List(of String)))
dim mid as new Dictionary(of String, List(of String)
dim leaf as new List(of String)
leaf.add("leaf1")
leaf.add("leaf2")
mid.add("middle", leaf)
base.add("base", mid)
```

Logical Representation:

```
               / leaf
        mid    - leaf
     /         \ leaf
base
     \         / leaf
        mid    - leaf
               \ leaf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing built in. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing builtin, you're probably better off building your own class for each tree node.

```
public class Node {
  private List<Node> children = new List<Node>();

  public void Node(Node parent,Object node_data) {
    ...
  }

  // put some methods for adding, removing, retrieving children here
}
```

And only one private generic class!