# Linq query recursion

Tags: linq, recursion

I work in C# and Entity framework.
I have a table in my database named Genre. Here are its attributes:
idGenre, name, idParentGenre.

For example. the values would be:

(idGenre = 1, name = "acoustic", idParentGenre=2)

(idGenre = 2, name = "rock", idParentGenre=2)

(idGenre = 3, name = "country", idParentGenre=4)

(idGenre = 4, name = "folk", idParentGenre=5)

(idGenre = 5, name = "someOtherGenre", idParentGenre=5)

As you can see, it's kind of a tree.

Now, I have a method for searching through this table. The input parameter is idGenre and idParentGenre. I should return if the genre (idGenre) is a son/grandchild/grandgrandchild/...  of idParentGenre.

For example, I get idGenre=3, idParentGenre=5, I should return true.

However, there isn't recursion in Linq. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "recursion in Linq". Can you show the method that you have? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Do it the old fashion way.  LINQ is great, but it cannot solve every problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a method to handle this instead of using LINQ:

```
bool HasParent(int genre, int parent)
{
    Genre item = db.Genres.FirstOrDefault(g => g.IdGenre == genre);
    if (item == null)
        return false;

    // If there is no parent, return false, 
    // this is assuming it's defined as int?
    if (!item.idParentGenre.HasValue)
        return false;

    if (item.idParentGenre.Value == parent)
        return true;

    return HasParent(item.idParentGenre, parent);
}
```

This lets you handle this in a single recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to implement a tree without using a tree.

Have you considered...using a tree? Here's a [great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp) and some answers you could build off (including one with [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012855/1100441):

```
delegate void TreeVisitor<T>(T nodeData);

class NTree<T>
{
    T data;
    LinkedList<NTree<T>> children;

    public NTree(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        children = new LinkedList<NTree<T>>();
    }

    public void addChild(T data)
    {
        children.AddFirst(new NTree<T>(data));
    }

    public NTree<T> getChild(int i)
    {
        foreach (NTree<T> n in children)
            if (--i == 0) return n;
        return null;
    }

    public void traverse(NTree<T> node, TreeVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
        visitor(node.data);
        foreach (NTree<T> kid in node.children)
            traverse(kid, visitor);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I can't use a tree. I have a table in my database for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Bring the table of genres in the memory (it cannot be that big), and recursively traverse it to create a mapping between an `idGenre` and a transitive closure of its descendents, like this:

```
1: {1, 2}
2: {2}
3: {3, 4, 5}
4: {4, 5}
5: {5}
```

The data above stays **only in memory**. You recompute it every time on start-up, and on updates to the genres table.

When it is time to query for all songs in a specific genre, use the pre-calculated table in an `idGenre in ...` query, like this:

```
IEnumerable<Song> SongsWithGenreId(int idGenre) {
    var idClosure = idToIdClosure[idGenre];
    return context.Songs.Where(song => idClosure.Contains(song.idGenre));
}
```

Comment: But this isn't a perfect solution. I already have a place where I place the id of the parent (this place is the table), I don't think another place for the same purpose is good.

Comment: @Srcee It isn't "another place" to store your data, it's a cache of the same data, only preprocessed. Your queries would be very fast - much faster than anything else suggested so far, because there will be only one roundtrip. All the recursion would be baked into the structure of the `idToIdClosure` dictionary, which is good, because genres do not change all that often.