# Replacing TreeView with a non-GUI option

Tags: c#, class, user-interface, tree, treeview

I'm working on a project that heavily uses TreeView and TreeNodes.  However, I need to remove the GUI from the existing program and allow it to run through in the console.  I'm new to C# but I'm having trouble finding a similar class without the GUI.  What would be the recommended class to implement?  From what I understand there is no Tree base class but would I be able to create my own?

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for a non-GUI Tree data structure into which you can place some type of objects?

Comment: Hey man, you accepted really fast (which is an awesome, good S.O. citizen type thing to do!) If you have any more questions feel free to ask me to flesh some of it out.  I assume you'll comfortable enough programming to make something useful out of this, but just in case....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tree data structure in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm going through the code again and I think it would be easier to simply use Dictionary instead, but the current implementation is using InvokeRequired and I'm not sure how to substitute that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trees are simply `List<Node>`s where `Node` is a class containing a `List<Node>` and any other important Data. How easy it is to implement depends on a lot of things, but you shouldn't have much trouble:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private List<Node<T>> nodes;        

    public T Item { get; private set; }

    public Node(T item) {
        nodes = new List<Node<T>>();
        Item = item;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Node<T>> {
        return nodes;
    }

    //Add other things like: `Find(T item)`, `Add(T item)`
}
```

If you so desire you can create a `Tree<T>` class that encapsulates some searching/manipulating functions, but that should get you headed in the right direction.