# What collection to store a tree structure?

Tags: c#, collections, tree

I want to store an organisation chart in a collection. I think a tree data structure will be best suited to my needs, as I need to add multiple nodes to one node.

`LinkedList` only provides adding one node to another node, if I understand it correctly.

I have looked at C5 `treeset` collection, but it doesn't seem to have `Add()` method to add more than 2 nodes to one node.

I have also looked at `Treeview` class from Windows Forms library, but I do not want to add Windows forms *dll* to my project, since I am building a service layer application. (or is it fine?)

I do not want to write my own tree collection class, if there is already one provided by 3rd party?

Any suggestion please?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: Thanks ikh I have seen that link, but I do not want to create my own collection. There must be someone out there who has created one dll and distributed it through Nuget!

Comment: The problem with pre-built tree-like collections is that there is no agreement on the generally accepted interface. Unlike lists, sets, or dictionaries, trees and graphs could have vastly different interfaces depending on who is implementing them, and for what purpose they need to utilize them. C# makes it rather easy to roll your own, and that is something I would definitely recommend doing in your situation.

Comment: Why not Write your own? a simple tree class takes about 10 minutes to write.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Something like this can be a starting point. By using generics this one can hold a tree of anything

```
class TreeNode<T>
{
    List<TreeNode<T>> Children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();

    T Item {get;set;}

    public TreeNode (T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(T item)
    {
        TreeNode<T> nodeItem = new TreeNode<T>(item);
        Children.Add(nodeItem);
        return nodeItem;
    }
}
```

A sample which holds a tree of strings

```
string root = "root";
TreeNode<string> myTreeRoot = new TreeNode<string>(root);
var first = myTreeRoot.AddChild("first child");
var second = myTreeRoot.AddChild("second child");
var grandChild = first.AddChild("first child's child");
```