# Suitable data types in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I would like to store and process information which I have in following format.

Please let me know what are the suitable data types available in C# to achieve this requirement.

Also "stat" is additional information which I would like to attach with each node. How should I carry that with each node.

```
Root -stat
       |
       !_Node1 - stat
       |         |_Node1-1  stat
       |       
       |_Node2 -stat
         |_Node2-1 - stat
```

Comment: you want to know Data Structure???

Comment: You might want to take a look at this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
public class Node
{
    public string Stat;
    public List<Node> Children;
}
```

Comment: sorry for that , yes I would like to know the data structure.

Comment: @user987316 it is called as **tree**

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is a [composite patern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) :

> Component :
>
> - is the abstraction for all components, including composite ones    declares the interface for objects in the composition
> - (optional) defines an interface for accessing a component's parent in    the recursive structure, and implements it if that's appropriate
>
> Leaf :
>
> - represents leaf objects in the composition .
> - implements all Component methods
>
> Composite :
>
> - represents a composite Component (component having children)
> - implements methods to manipulate children
> - implements all Component methods, generally by delegating them to its    children

[image]