# How to traverse a tree with multiple branches

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf, algorithm

I'm working on an experimental TreeView where each TreeViewItem can either represent a condition, or a branch with an operator. This is to be parsed into SQL.

For example, the tree could have a branch with an "AND" or an "OR" operator, whose children would then be conditions. This is used to as to be able to generate the `WHERE` segment of an SQL statement, for example `((Name = 'Matt' AND AGE > 20) OR (Name = 'John' AND Age = 15)) AND Job = 'Student'`.

How can I go about constructing that? What I've done so far is thought about placing a `string,list<Condition>` pair in a `Tuple<>`, where the string represents the branch operator (AND/OR), and the list represents the conditions contained within that branch.

However, since each branch can be split into a number of operator branches or conditions, it can get extremely complicated very quickly

Comment: you probably need a tree data structure : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp

Comment: Is the `treeview` already there for you to parse, or you need to build the `treeview` too?

Comment: @Bolu The TreeView is already there for me to parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive function to parse the `treeview` from top, so each root note of the treeview is one SQL statement:

e.g.:

[image]

function code:

```
string getHead(TreeViewItem t)
            {
                string s = "";
                if (t.Items.Count == 0) //get the condition
                {
                    return s=t.Header.ToString(); //change this to your real getCondition function.
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < t.Items.Count; i++ )
                    {
                        if(t.Items[i] is TreeViewItem) //Edit: only use treeviewitems not the button...
                        {
                          if (i == 0) // first note doesn't need the operator 
                          {
                            s += getHead(t.Items[0] as TreeViewItem);
                          }
                          else // only needs operator in between
                          {
                             s += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(getHead(t.Items[i] as TreeViewItem).Trim()) ? "" : (" " + t.Header + " " + getHead(t.Items[i] as TreeViewItem))); // only get real treeviewitem, not the one with two buttons and an empty header; change t.Header to your real getOperator function.

                          }
                        }                    
                    }
                    return string.Format("({0})",s); //group sub conditions
                }
            }
```

usage:

```
MessageBox.Show(getHead((treeView1.Items[0] as TreeViewItem)));
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, after each and every branch, I've got a TreeViewItem with a button. How can it skip that and still work recursively?

Comment: @DotNET, Updated, you need to add `if(t.Items[i] is TreeViewItem)`

Comment: Hi again, I've almost got it working. For some reason, it keeps adding an "AND" or an "OR" at the end though.

So I'm getting something like `(ID=5 AND Name=Matt AND)`

Comment: @DotNET, can you post your xaml for the `treeview`? I guess you have some empty `treeviewitem` (item without a header)

Comment: I haven't got any XAML as the TreeView is generated at run-time by the user. If it helps, could I post a diagram explaining the structure?

Comment: @DotNET, updated, change the code in the `Else` to `s += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(getHead(t.Items[i] as TreeViewItem).Trim()) ? "" : (" " + t.Header + " " + getHead(t.Items[i] as TreeViewItem)));`

Comment: I'll give it a try :) Sorry about taking long to reply, but the code requires a lot of modification since each TreeViewItem has a number of components inside. I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Thanks! this is just the principle.

Answer (score 0):

In your tree view, aren't the last AND and OR supposed to be interchanged? I cannot get to the same parsed string you specified below with that view.

```
AND
    AND
         Job='Student'
         Age > 20
    AND
         OR
            Name='John'
            Name='Matt'
         Sex='Male'
```

The last AND ands another OR condition and a single statement.

Not sure if this helps, but bison generates C code for bottom up parsing like this. You can give it a try.

```
e: conditional statement|
   e AND e|
   e OR e
;
```

Comment: What I provided was just an example. The user can modify the tree as he pleases