# How to code variable loop level in foreach in List<T>

Tags: c#, foreach

I have the following class:

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

And I created an instance of this class, fox ex.

```
Person pers = new Person();
```

I can code foreach loops statically and store the Children in some list:

```
foreach (var item in pers.Children)
{
    List<Person> r = item.Children;
    foreach (var item2 in item.Children)
    {
        List<Person> k = item2.Children;
        foreach (var item3 in item2.Children)
        {
        etc..
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, how to code the foreach loops, if the "**pers**" has a children, and one of his children (**pers.Children**) also has a children. It's something like genealogical tree.

**I mean, how to make it more dynamically?** Because I don't know how the structure of the family can be.

Edit:
I just want to show all the successors of one person. For example just names of his successors

Comment: You can solve it recursivelly but you should describe what you actually want to perform with this genealogical tree in order to get specific answers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the deep childrens list? Recuresivity is what you need... but how? I can't help as far as I don't know what you are trying to fulfil.

Comment: I just want to show all the successors of one person. For example just names of his successors

Comment: Ok then update your question :)

Comment: You can do this with standard recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursion :

```
public static void ShowAll(Person pers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pers.Name);
    foreach (var item in pers.Children)
    {
        ShowAll(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is to add a method to your class which will show the person's name (and/or other data) and then display their children's names (and/or other data) by calling the method on each child instance.

The nice thing about this approach is that it makes your code much cleaner and leaves it to the `Person` class to handle how it displays itself (and it's successors).

Here's an example of your class modified with such a method:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Children = new List<Person>();
    }

    public void DisplaySuccessors(int indendationLevel = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", new String('.', indendationLevel * 2), Name);

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.DisplaySuccessors(indendationLevel + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how you could use it:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var mother = new Person {Name = "Mother"};

    var daughter1 = new Person {Name = "daughter1"};
    var granddaughter1 = new Person { Name = "granddaughter1" };

    var son1 = new Person { Name = "son1" };
    var grandson1 = new Person { Name = "grandson1" };
    var granddaughter2 = new Person { Name = "granddaughter2" };

    mother.Children.Add(daughter1);
    mother.Children.Add(son1);
    daughter1.Children.Add(granddaughter1);
    son1.Children.Add(grandson1);
    son1.Children.Add(granddaughter2);

    mother.DisplaySuccessors();
}
```

Output:

> Mother 
>   ..daughter1 
>   ....granddaughter1 
>   ..son1 
>   ....grandson1 
>   ....granddaughter2

Answer (score 0):

Handling tree like data structures has already been intensively discussed:
[Tree Data Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

One way is *recursion*, like this method which calls itself:

```
static void WriteAllSuccessors(Person pers, int depth = 0)
{
  var indent = new string(' ', depth * 4);
  Console.WriteLine(indent + pers.Name);
  foreach (var child in pers.Children)
      WriteAllSuccessors(child, depth + 1);
}
```

Note the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard recursion, where you call itself and add nodes to some list:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> successors = new List<Person>();

            var person = new Person()
            {
                Name = "GrandFather",
                Children = new List<Person>()
                {
                    new Person()
                    {
                        Name = "Son",
                        Children = new List<Person>()
                        {
                            new Person()
                            {
                                Name = "SonOfSon"
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Person()
                    {
                        Name = "Daughter",
                        Children = new List<Person>()
                        {
                            new Person()
                            {
                                Name = "DaughterOfDaughter"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            SearchForSuccessors(person.Children, successors);
        }

        public static void SearchForSuccessors(List<Person> persons, List<Person> successors)
        {
            foreach(var person in persons )
            {
                successors.Add(person);

                if (person.Children != null)
                    SearchForSuccessors(person.Children, successors);
            }
        }
```