# Converting datatable into hierarchical data structure (JSON) using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, c#-4.0

I am executing a SQL query into datatable. The query can return multiple columns. The result is in key value format and represent hierarchical data. See the below screenshot.

[image]

The image shows 3 parts. First the data, then the hierarchical representation of data and JSON equivalent.

Currently the image shows 4 level of data, but we can have 6-7 levels of data. The format will remain same but the number of columns can change.

How can i get the desired result using C#? ? I  know it is basic programming but I am having hard time with it.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?  Do you need to take data from SQL and put it into JSON?  Or are you reading the JSON and want to store it in a C# object (data structure)?  The data you have described looks like a [Tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29).  A quick search indicated [these aren't available in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/66956/5329728) by default, but they are a simple structure to build.  Also look at [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3142495).

Comment: @Ian. I need to read data from SQL server & I want to pass this data to front end application developed using  angularJS. So I need to convert the data into tree structure. I cannot just convert the data into JSON, first i need to get data into required format.

Comment: So you want to go `SQL` -> `C# data structure` -> `JSON`?  If you're using Entity Framework it should generate a model for you from the SQL.

Comment: I am not using entity framework :(

Comment: Then what are you using to read from the database?

Comment: Assuming you are using something like Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL, you probably want to use LINQ with GroupBy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Comment: @JackA. I am actually using DAX queries and executing it over SQL tabular database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a fixed-level hierarchy like you are showing in your example, you can use a [LINQ query with grouping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to generate the tree structure for your JSON. Here is an example with a three-level hierarchy:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new List<Data>
    {
        new Data("Food", "1_g", "beverage", "2_b", "hot", "3_h"),
        new Data("Food", "1_g", "beverage", "2_b", "cold", "3_c"),
        new Data("Food", "1_g", "fruit", "2_f", "juicy", "3_j"),
        new Data("Food", "1_g", "fruit", "2_f", "solid", "3_s"),
        new Data("Food", "1_g", "cookie", "2_c", "chocolate", "3_cho"),
    };

    var tree = from l1 in data
                group l1 by new { key = l1.Key_L1, name = l1.L1 } into group1
                select new
                {
                    key = group1.Key.key,
                    name = group1.Key.name,
                    children = from l2 in group1
                                group l2 by new { key = l2.Key_L2, name = l2.L2 } into group2
                                select new
                                {
                                    key = group2.Key.key,
                                    name = group2.Key.name,
                                    children = from l3 in group2
                                                select new { key = l3.Key_L3, name = l3.L3 }
                                }
                };

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Console.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(tree));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

class Data
{
    public Data(string l1, string k1, string l2, string k2, string l3, string k3)
    {
        L1 = l1; Key_L1 = k1;
        L2 = l2; Key_L2 = k2;
        L3 = l3; Key_L3 = k3;
    }
    public string L1 { get; set; }
    public string Key_L1 { get; set; }
    public string L2 { get; set; }
    public string Key_L2 { get; set; }
    public string L3 { get; set; }
    public string Key_L3 { get; set; }
}
```

The above is a working example of the technique using POCOs.

You mention "datatable"; I assume this is referring to the [.NET `DataTable` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? If so, you can use LINQ to query a `DataTable`. You just need to convert it to an enumerable using the DataSetExtensions. See: [LINQ query on a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable)

Then in the LINQ statement, you replace the list with your data table `.AsEnumerable()` and replace the property references with `.Field<string>("")`. Like so:

```
DataTable dt = // load data table
var tree = from l1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
           group l1 by new { key = l1.Field<string>("Key_L1"), name = l1.Field<string>("L1") } into group1
           select new
           {
               // etc.
           };
```

For a variable number of columns, you have to use a recursive approach, like so:

```
var tree = Descend(dt.AsEnumerable(), 1, 3);

private static System.Collections.IEnumerable Descend(IEnumerable<DataRow> data, int currentLevel, int maxLevel)
{
    if (currentLevel > maxLevel)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<object>();
    }
    return from item in data
            group item by new
            {
                key = item.Field<string>("Key_L" + currentLevel),
                name = item.Field<string>("L" + currentLevel)
            } into rowGroup
            select new
            {
                key = rowGroup.Key.key,
                name = rowGroup.Key.name,
                children = Descend(rowGroup, currentLevel + 1, maxLevel)
            };
}
```

One thing to note is that this approach creates an empty `children` collection on the leaf nodes.

Comment: Thanks !!!! yes, I was talking about using .net datatable class. I just wonder if we can make it more dynamic to pick multiple category.

Comment: I want to make use of .net DataTable class, so I don't have to create the structure (`data class in this case`) myself. Can you please include an example with datatable as well.

Comment: @OpenStack Did you look at the LINQ-to-DataTable article? Anyway, I include a brief example.