# Generic to self

Tags: c#, generics

I wanna make generic tree.

I have base class like:

```
public class TreeItemModelBase<T>
{
    protected List<T> children;
    ...
}
```

and derived classes like:

```
public class StorageTreeItemModel : TreeItemModelBase<StorageTreeItemModel>
{
     ...
}
```

Is this OK? I am not sure if I can use generic like this (Use StorageTreeItemModel like T).

Thank you

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, inheriting a generic class or implementing a generic interface using your own class as a generic type parameter is fine.

Implementations that avoid this are available and personally I think they are easier to understand, but as long as you are happy with the code, from a technical side there is nothing wrong with it.