# Create Nested Lists and return list of custom object type

Tags: c#, data-structures

Im trying to create a nested list that will return something like so.

- A

  - B
  - C
- D

  - E

I created a basic class:

```
public class MyClass
    {       
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public MyClass(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }         
    }
```

I created my method to setup my default nested list:

```
public List<MyClass> CreateList()
    {

        List<List<List<string>>> MyList = new List<List<List<string>>>
        { new List<List<string>> {new List<string> {"A"}, new 
          List<string> {"B", "C", "D", "E"}},
          new List<List<string>> {new List<string> {"F"}, new 
          List<string> {"G", "H"}},
        };

        var a = MyList.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
        var b = a.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
        List<MyClass> abc= b.Cast<MyClass>().ToList();                       

        return abc;
    }
```

I know this list is not being setup correctly but also this cast will not work. How can I properly setup this list and cast correctly? I must return a list, array or IEnumerable from my method.

Comment: Why not just add a Children property to `MyClass`?

Comment: Lots of good tree structure examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a tree structure for your objects, you can get there easily by adding a "Children" property to your class.  I would suggest using a `List<T>` for this:

```
public class MyClass    
{       
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<MyClass> Children { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        Children = new List<MyClass>();
        Name = name;
    }       

    //Added a new constructor so we can pass an IEnumerable of children on creation
    public MyClass(string name, IEnumerable<MyClass> children)
    {
        Children = new List<MyClass>(children);
        Name = name;           
    }
}
```

Then to make the nested list you want you would just do:

```
var myList = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass("A", new []
        {
            new MyClass("B"),
            new MyClass("C"),
        }),
    new MyClass("D", new []
        {
            new MyClass("E")
        })
};
```

The result would be a single class that can have a hierarchy when used in a collection.  Your "top level" would be a collection (List, array, etc) of `MyClass`.  Then each item in that collection has its own children, which can have their own children, etc, etc.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NMOASw)

Comment: This is good. I would suggest using an `IEnumerable` interface for the constructor instead.

Comment: @JuanR only reason I didnt is because I pass a List and the property is a List.  Wouldnt want to call `.ToList()` for no reason.  But I will make a note in my answer

Comment: @maccettura Thanks very helpful and solved my issue!

Comment: @maccettura: Your target container is a list but you only need an enumeration to populate it so there is no reason to constraint the consumer to use a `List`. They could create an array and pass it to the constructor and still populate the list correctly. If the user does not want the list to mutate, he could also expose the `Children` property as an `IEnumerable`.