# Is there an official Tree C# implementation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tree

Is there any official tree data structure in C#? I need it for ASP.NET Core. 
I need to build, level by level, a file system tree.
And then search for elements and so on.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tree data structure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Why do you need to build a tree of the file system before you walk it?

Comment: Here's my favourite implementation of a tree: `public class Tree<T> : List<Tree<T>> { public T Value { get; private set; } }`.

Comment: It's quite trivial to add a visitor pattern to that to do searches.

Comment: thanks for your answers.
The reason why I need to buiñld the tree before walking it, is because I retrieve it from a Web Service. This WS can't give me at once the whole tree, so I need to request for it directory per directory.
I will implement it on my own :)