# Hierarchical Data Structure Menu in C# Console Application .Net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I need some help in creating a hierarchical data structure menu items in console application using .NET Core.

I want the structure to be similar to below.

Parent

- Child 1
  --Another Child 1A
  --Another Child 2A
  --- Another Sub Child 1A
- Child 2
  --Another Child 1B

Comment: Can I request for an example help please

Comment: What you're looking for is a Tree structure, I guess. There's a million implementations of trees already in the wild. Find one that fits your needs.

Comment: Can you please point at one example to get a basic idea? I am struggling to find a good example

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't, there's not a 'one size fits all' approach for trees, but you can get a grasp of what a tree can be like in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893/tree-data-structure-in-c-sharp

Comment: I will take a look at the examples and will try to come out with an answer. Thank you for taking time. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:

```
  public class Child
  {
      public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
  }
```

And if you want some sort of tree structure:

```
  var child1 = new Child() 
  { 
      Children = new List<Child>
           new Child(),
           new Child() { Children = new List<Child> { new Child() } },
           new Child()            
  };
```

Or this

```
  var child1 = new Child();
  var child2 = new Child();
  var child3 = new Child();
  var child4 = new Child();
  var child5 = new Child();

  child1.Children = new List<Child>{ child2, child3 };
  child3.Children = new List<Child> { child4, child5 };
```

Please note that there might be data integrity issues since List is exposed as public, meaning anybody can change Children or its contents, but you can look at that later.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do;

```
public class Child{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public Child subChild{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I am doing. Will paste the exact answer once I am done. Thank you.